# Accepting user input base on wildcard variables via batch

Tags: batch-file, compare, user-input

I don't know how to phrase this question so you guys understand, but bear with me. Below is my code:

```
set var1=yes no ok get out of here exit quit

echo Do you want to start?

set /p options=Your Input:

if "%Options%" (This is what I need help with)
```

Compare user input to var1 and if true, goto nextquestion
Even if user input 'Go start', it would match either Go or Start to var1. Since Go isn't on the list, it would try to match Start with var1. And if found, proceed to next question. Hope that makes sense

Comment: so, if any of the words of the Input is in the list, it should fire some action? If user enters `I want a piece of cake` it should fire because of the word `of`?

Comment: The logic within your question makes no sense. Your code asks a yes/no question. Yet you imply you want to go to the next question if the user answers yes or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in (%options%) do for %%b in (%var1%) do if /i "%%a"=="%%b" goto nextq
:not_found
response "%options%" is not implemented
pause
```

Proof of code:

```
c:\106x>q34542866
Do you want to start?
Your Input:go
User input was "go"
response "go" is not implemented

c:\106x>q34542866
Do you want to start?
Your Input:no
User input was "no"
response "no" found

c:\106x>q34542866
Do you want to start?
Your Input:exit
User input was "exit"
response "exit" found

c:\106x>q34542866
Do you want to start?
Your Input:go start
User input was "go start"
response "go start" is not implemented

c:\106x>q34542866
Do you want to start?
Your Input:I do want to start, yes please
User input was "I do want to start, yes please"
response "I do want to start, yes please" found
```

with code:

```dos
set var1=yes no ok get out of here exit quit
echo Do you want to start?
set /p options=Your Input:

ECHO User input was "%options%"

for %%a in (%options%) do for %%b in (%var1%) do if /i "%%a"=="%%b" goto nextq
:not_found
ECHO response "%options%" is not implemented

GOTO :EOF

:nextq
ECHO response "%options%" found

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. It takes any word and response that it was not implemented eventhough the word does contain in variables.

Comment: If any input word matches any of the words in `var1` then the procedure goes to `:nextq`. If not, it reports `not implemented`. Without examples, it's impossible to respond properly to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var1= yes no ok get out of here exit quit "
echo Do you want to start?
set /p options=Your Input:

for %%a in (%options%) do if "!var1: %%a =!" neq "%var1%" goto nextquestion
echo Word not found...
goto :EOF

:nextquestion
echo Word found
```